# error response from daemon container is not running

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Im running ubuntu terminal 18.04 on window 10 Pro , Im getting error while running ./startFabric.sh 
Error response from daemon: Container d827b753c3fda5ca92ada94c28e6362ebab32960f2af8805b4c9706e0056734d is not running
I have tried all the methods posted previously, can anyone please help me?

I tried removing all the container by using command docker ps -qa | xargs docker rm -f

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQtRB.png

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to run the Hyperledger Composer simple fabric development server (which is basically a very simple hyperledger fabric environment to help you get started with composer using a hyperledger fabric network) inside a windows subsystem layer for linux environment. This isn't supported on Windows (either in git bash or in windows subsystem layer for linux). 
If you are looking to use hyperledger composer then you should use a hypervisor to run a real linux VM such as virtualbox, vmware or hyperv (however it is highly recommended that you now invest time in the new programming models in hyperledger fabric rather than use hyperledger composer)
If you are looking to just using hyperledger fabric then you can start by looking at
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html